Error connecting to MySQL 8.0 database using .Net Core
I am trying to connect to MYSql 8.0 database using the following code in simple .NET core console app.
string countryName = "Chile";
var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    Server = "localhost",
    Port = 3306,
    UserID = "xxxx",
    Password = "xxxx",
    Database = "world"
};
string connString = builder.ToString();
string query = "select code from country where countryName = @countryName";
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(countryName, countryName);

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    command.Connection = conn;
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    dataTable.Load(reader);
    reader.Close();
    conn.Close();
}

I have added the following as dependencies in my console app.
MySQL.Data 8.3.0
I am getting the following error for a simple connection.
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.
  Source=MySql.Data
  StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager.IsReplicationGroup(String groupName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.<OpenAsync>d__100.MoveNext()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception.

Inner Exception 2:
ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize

Inner Exception 3:
ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section add. 

I am trying to follow a simple example listed at
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html
What am I doing wrong?
I'm able to connect to mysql server using workbench and SQLyog using the same credentials.
Total frustration to make a simple connection to a database. Please help

may be there command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countryName", countryName);

I changed it to string query = "select code from country where countryName = 'Chile'"; and then commented out the command.Parameters just to test it. But it still fails with the same error

Sorry, I found my mistake. The a section in the App.config file was not properly defined.
